# How to import Azure Function App in Azure API Management using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to create API management instance and import Azure Function App which has HTTP trigger binding, I am not sure how I can import this in Terraform resource "**[azurerm_api_management_api](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management_api.html)**".

I am using Azure Function V2 runtime to create my apis.

I expect to use Terraform to import my apis (built in Azure Functions v2) into api management instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating Swagger spec for your Azure Function App and then use 'import' argument for "azurerm_api_management_api" to import it. Example here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management_api.html

Comment: link error, should be https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api